# Can a Chrome extension use a remote source for building an array?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that does a bunch of things for an online game. One of the functions I added recently replaces a persons in-game avatar with a custom image hosted outside of the game. I actually host them on my web server. To do this I'm written some Jquery that looks for specific elements and if the image URL is one of the ones requested by a specific player I substitute the image they have requested. This works fine but, is cumbersome every time a new player requests a substituted image because I have to write the new static substitution into the Chrome extension and then republish it. My hope is that the function can be written in a way that looks at an external source and builds an array that will be used to do the substitutions. An example of one of the current seven static substitutions is below.

```
$('td.nameCell2').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('style', $(this).attr('style').replace("https://www.heroesrisinggame.com/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png", "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/FJinstead.png"));});
```

Is something like this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Chrome.storage.api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) create multiple key/pair objects.

```
[{'pic1':'pic1.png'}].
```

When you want to reference pics for the replacement, you can loop through or index Chrome.storage.

Comment: But I'd still have to republish the extension any time I wanted to add a new pair. What I'm hoping for is something that will let me edit an external collection of fairs on the fly and have the extension look to that source for it's image replacement. Something like a JSON query?

Comment: Not if your chrome extension is creating, storing, and loading the location in text string.  Maybe I don't follow you exactly.  If all your location to the pics were stored in Chrome.storage.  My psuedo code would be, username.avatar = 'https://www.heroesrisinggame.com/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png'.  My update button would loop through the stored objects, find the username, and edit what is for the image location value.  When the game loads or looks for the value of the username, it would input what is stored.

Comment: These are on a per player request basis. I don't know which player will have an image substitution until they ask me to do one. I also have no access to the game server except what any other player would have. When a player asks me to do a substitution I look them up in the game and find out what the URL is that points to their avatar image. I then place the alternate image on my web server and get it's URL. Then I tell the Chrome extension that if the object class is .avatar (for example) and the URL for the image is https://blah.blah.blah then replace it with https://alt.image.alt.

Comment: So if the extension is just replacing the link in the image dom elements, could the extension have an upload button that uploaded the image location to local storage.  Script it to always change the avatar's external url link, and replaced with what you have in local storage.  

This would eliminate having to retrieve the image from your webserver, you can have the image reside locally and they can manage it themselves.  

Also and most importantly, you wouldn't need to keep republishing the extension because it's always modifying the avatar's location link with what's stored locally.

Comment: They want everyone with the extension to see their custom avatar though, not just the individual customizing theirs.

Comment: You should simply have a way for the guests to login and upload to their respective folders.    Then have the upload button perform the loop based off of the current logged in username, and change the image in their respective folder.  Therefore, you don't need to change any url locations on your webserver's end.  Just modify your code above, .replace("https://www.heroesrisinggame.com/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png", "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/USER/FJinstead.png")

Comment: If you want a universal applied, the imgs must be pulled centrally.  If you don't want to republish the extension, build it so that the extension is only uploading the file, but keeping the same name.  Overwriting it I guess.  Therefore the game is always looking for the same file.